# Codename One treating label text as string literal in iOS?

Tags: java, ios, codenameone

The app that I've built it a journaling app, and users can go back and look at their previous entries from a calendar page (screenshot attached). On iPhone only (Android is fine), after clicking through about 20 days the app crashes. It doesn't send a crash message through email, so I'm pretty sure that it's hitting a memory limit.

In testing, I kept all of my logic the same and only removed the part where I generate the spanlabel to show the journal text. I was still pulling the text from the database, just not creating the label and displaying it. And it stopped the crashing.

So my question is, is there anything I can do to make sure that the text that goes into the label does not get stored in memory, so that the garbage collector can remove it?

[image]

Comment: `SpanLabel` should be collected just like everything else. There might be a memory leak that appears more sever on iOS since memory is arranged differently there. I suggest using a memory profiler and verifying that the object is indeed collected in JavaSE.  If you have access to a Mac using the xcode memory profiler can also give us a hint about the source of the memory leak.

Comment: I don't own a Mac, but I should be able to get my hands on one for testing

Comment: I suggest starting with a Java based profiler. It won't show a crash but it might show a leak

Comment: It turned out not to be a memory leak, but rather a problem with the Database connection not properly being closed. I've opened an issue for it here:

https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3515

And if there's anything I can do to help it get fixed, please let me know. It's causing me and everyone who uses my app so much trouble, as it's constantly crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem is caused when several really small queries run consecutively. After removing those the larger queries run without crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're closing the DB from the "right thread"? iOS is super sensitive about the thread used for DB access. Also make sure you close the cursor first and the DB after if you do close it.

I suggest reproducing this on the simulator by placing a breakpoint in the cursor `close()` method and seeing who invoked it. If our finalizer method reaches the cursor then you have a bug of leaving an open cursor somewhere that you can reproduce in the simulator. At this point you can log every cursor opening then see which cursor wasn't cleaned up. Make sure all cursor openings are coded defensively with a finally block.

Comment: I tried your suggestions and didn't find anything conclusive, so perhaps I was wrong about the cursor openness causing the problem. Using the simulator, for every opening/closing of a cursor, I logged:

[EDT] 0:0:1,268 - OPEN  com.codename1.impl.javase.SECursor@115c4b25
[EDT] 0:0:1,268 - CLOSE com.codename1.impl.javase.SECursor@115c4b25

I ran a quick powershell script on the logging output of 5890 lines and every open was followed by a close with the same @id, and every call started with [EDT] (meaning they are all on the main EDT thread?)

Comment: Odd. Is it possible that one of the calls is outside of the finally block? or not the first statement there. That means you could get an exception only on the device and leave something dangling.

Comment: I don't believe so. I've created a full test case here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jd41GZ4adnK1FubTfDc9x4OS9gdFPjok/view?usp=sharing 
The DBFunctions class is where all of the database calls come from. I ran this code on a 2020 Apple iPad Air and after I've clicked on 4 days it crashes consistently. If there's any way that you can look at this code, or test it, I would appreciate it so much. I don't have the knowledge of how iOS code needs to work and I've tried absolutely everything that I can think of to fix it, and nothing has worked. Please, please help.

Comment: I see Steve is following up with you on the issue, I'm afraid SQLite in iOS is just inherently pretty awful.